# What is the meaning of the term "trade size"

Tags: wiring

While shopping for electrical parts for the next project, I keep seeing the term Trade Size.  What exactly is this a measure of?

Answer (score 6):

It simply means what the item is referred to in size, .vs. what any actual dimension may be. "Nominal" size means the same thing.

So, 1/2" EMT (for example) is 0.706" on the outside and 0.622" on the inside, and 0.500" nowhere.

Comment: Same as how wood 2x4s are actually 1.5x3.5s

Comment: Your example only gives 1 example, there are many trades and at least 3 common ones that use different measurement / schedule of thickness , ID or OD and when the measurements were common for example trade size of dimential lumber has changed over the years and depending on the schedule of a pipe and the type it can have big differences. 1/2 inch copper pipe for plumbing is not the same size as 1/2 inch copper for hvac one uses ID one uses OD.

Answer (score 0):

"Trade size" is a measure of the diameter of the component wire. Also used in light duty chain.
Specifically you can read "trade size" as "Wire Guage"
18 = 18,
16 = 16
etc. You can see a table here:
https://www.chain-cable.com/weldless_chains.htm

Comment: If it was only electrical I think the term would be different. Depending on the Trade , plumbing/ electrical, hvac, or wood working the way things are measured are different and have changed in some cases over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Trade size depends on what trade we are talking about and the material. With HVAC copper we measure the outside diameter, with plumbing we measure the inside diameter, with wood demintional lumber it has changed over the years but is based on the outside dimensions where in the 1900's a 2x4 was a true measure of 2"x4" today not the same. So it depends on the Trade you are talking about what the measurements will really be. I see this the most in the electrical trade because of code requirements but then the schedule or thickness of the conduit comes into play so there are slightly different id or od sizes , but even these change over the years, when I started in construction a 1/2" sheet of plywood was 1/2 inch now 15/32. So it depends on the Trade that you are looking at and the type of material.